# Keeping pigeons and their droppings away from other pets

Tags: health, feces, birds

We have a large number of pigeons in our backyward and doing some research I have found that the histoplasmosis and cryptococcosis diseases carried in their feces can be harmful to cats and dogs. Searching around I've seen some suggested solutions although a lot really wouldn't be useful in our situation:

- Barriers and various spices to keep them away where they roost - the yard is too open for barriers to be effective and they seem to fly in and wander around rather than nest in a particular area.
- Remove food sources - we did the obvious step of bringing the dog bowl back inside some time ago but we have a lot of trees and they seem quite content with amount of natural seed. Also we have budgies outside and while we try to sweep up the area often no doubt some sits there a while before we get to it.
- The various loud sound ideas wouldn't go down well in a residential area and I wonder if the ultrasonic options would also disturb our budgies and/or dog?

I don't know much about pigeons but one possible reason they may like to congregate here more than adjoining properties is that the previous owner used to breed / race them. Although that was close to twenty years ago so presumably it would have to be their offspring and I've never seen a sign of them actually nesting on the property.

We haven't had any problems so far with our pets contracting those diseases but the number seems to be on the increase. Given the above constraints does anyone have any other ideas that might be worth considering?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Zaralynda](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/224/zaralynda) [recommended](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2132/how-can-i-keep-my-neighbors-dogs-out-of-my-yard#comment4682_2132) a [motion activated sprinkler](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000071NUS) for [a dog problem I was having](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2132/how-can-i-keep-my-neighbors-dogs-out-of-my-yard).  If sensitive enough, I think this could work well for you.

You might also try some plastic replicas of predators like owls and snakes and Fake peregrine falcons, but without movement these tend to only work okay at best.

What you really need is something that flaps, like a sail or kite, or better yet a plastic predator replica that flaps.

They likely sell better versions of something like this at your local home store:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ETBP0pYzWaM

Comment: The owl would be a good option, they make some that are basically bobbleheads, or their heads swivel back and forth.

Answer (score 4):

All I can say is that my father races pigeons and in the 20 years having dogs, chickens and rabbits, no animal became sick, so I wouldn't be too worried.

A pigeon can become older then 20 years, but if the former pigeon owner is away from years, then it isn't his offspring. Pigeons needs food and if there's nothing to find, they leave...

Our oldest dog, a Labrador eats pigeon/cheap/dog/geese droppings.

Pigeons don't like strange bright objects, so you can try putting something like a flag to scare them.