# How do I keep my neighbor's cat from defecating in my yard?

Tags: cats, training, toilet-training, defecation

One of my neighbors (not sure which one) has a cat that keeps defecating in my yard, I keep finding remnants every other day.

While amusing, I don't have time to build the motion activated scare machines depicted in these videos

- [How to stop cats pissing on your car](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uIbkLjjlMV8)
- [How to stop cats forever](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=goZ2DqMnaGc&feature=share&list=UUmCkcCtmrBu5CfFi8LFFcVA&index=1)

However, commercial, and home made scented products seem to have mixed reviews:

- [shake away](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001ACRPMI)
- [liquid fence](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002Y2TKS)
- [citrus sent](http://www.thriftyfun.com/Homemade-Cat-Repellents.html)

Further, it seems that using a low voltage electric fence to deter cats and dogs is not allowed in the US.

### What cat deterrents actually work? Are there other ways to keep a cat from defecating all over my yard?

---

Related:
[How can I keep my neighbor's dogs out of my yard?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2132/how-can-i-keep-my-neighbors-dogs-out-of-my-yard)

Comment: Also of note, I have pet house rabbits (they stay indoors) so anything I might track in that is toxic to them is off limits.

Comment: Probably worth clarifying if you want him to stay out of your yard or just not poop there... lots of options for "keep out"

Comment: is the cat burying the poop or leaving it uncovered? what type of ground is he pooping on (sand, mulch, grass) and how willing would you be to relandscape?

Comment: @Zaralynda the poop is uncovered, but there are big holes all around the yard; I'm beginning to wonder if it's a cat at all as the poop often occurs in the wet corrner of the yard.

Comment: If deterrents don't work, try creating an attractive place instead - cats like soft ground like sand, so dig a pit in a secluded place and fill with easily diggable sand.  If it is a cat, it will prefer that spot and at least you know where it goes.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the quickest thing that comes to mind is the possibility of using a litter attractant at your property line. Basically, these are designed to attract cats to use litter boxes rather than undesirable locations, but you could look at that as an option for encouraging the cat onto his own property.

Now, this stuff isn't specifically intended for outdoor usage, so rain and other weather probably means a more frequent application, but if you know that you're in for a dry spell, then it might be worth a shot.

You could also put out a sheltered litter box and use the attractant in it. While it would still mean cleaning it up, at least it would be in a controlled location and less likely to be discovered through more unpleasant means...

Comment: humm, I was hopping for something to spray to deter them until they found a new place.  Over time, your solution is likely would add up to a similar commitment to a motion activated scare system.

Comment: @virtualxtc - Probably, but spread cost. In any event, I don't sense an effortless solution would exist.

Comment: in any case I do prefer your answer to the more obvious (but not yet pointed out) "get a dog".

Comment: @virtualxtc - Haha, I thought about the dog option, but I've seen cats cow pitbulls with a swipe to the nose, so I don't believe it will work. Besides, that's a *much* bigger effort in both the sort and long term...

Comment: You could try creating an attractant by moving the cat's poop over to the property line or a more appealing (less horrible) location. Not a financial expense and you're likely removing the poop anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of potential solutions, but in the end, unless you can keep an animal from entering your yard, you can't keep them from defecating/urinating in it.  Even this solution is not sufficient for birds who fly over, nor for animals who broadcast across and through fence.